# My code doesn't work

Tags: python, input, while-loop

I have a problem with my code. When I enter numbers it still shows "only numbers are allowed". How can I fix it?

This is the code:

```
age = input("What's your age? ")
while age != age.isdigit():
    print("only numbers are allowed")
    age = input("What's your age? ")
age = int(age)
```

Comment: `while not age.isdigit():`

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it now

Answer (score 1):

The expression `age.isdigit()` does *not* return a number.  It returns either `True` or `False`.  Therefore the condition `age != age.isdigit()` is comparing a string value in `age` to boolean `True` or `False` and this will *never* evaluate as true.

If you want the loop to continue while age is not a value all-digit string, you can use `while not age.isdigit()`.

You might also consider writing it this way:

```
 while true:
      age = input("What's your age? ")
      if age.isdigit():
           break

 age = int(age)
```

which I find easier to understand since you don't have to repeat the input prompt and you're not using a negative condition.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of - `while not age.is_digit():`? Also python bools are capitalized.

Comment: That is, in fact, exactly what I recommended.  Along with a possible alternative that I find easier to read, and that more rigorously adheres to DRY.

Comment: Ahhh I see. I missed that section.

Comment: I added it in an edit -- so you may not have missed it.  FIxed the bool literals.

Comment: Thank you very much! I get it now